# Syntax Errors when importing phonegap project to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm completely new to phonegap.
I just installed phonegap and made my first project .. but when i imported it on eclipse i found these errors
[image]

Is there any files i miss to include ?
I really stuck and need help here
Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you add the needed jar file, Make sure of that.

Comment: @Homosapiens ..Sorry but i don't know what jar file should i add

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `cordova jar` file in your project

Refer

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html